# Bound on global error of 2nd order Runge-Kutta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to find a second order Runge Kutta global error bound defined as
$$|Y_j-y_j|\leq L$$
where $Y_j$ is a true value and $y_j $ is approximation of the function at that point. Does anyone have any good references where I could read about this

Comment: What second order RK method? There are several, one could say infinitely many.

Comment: In the main idea, the proof https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2365882/115115 applies, only that the $e_i$ have size $O(h^3)$, the constant depending on the truncation error, giving a global error $O(h^2)$.